# Adding MySQL data to Google Charts via PHP

Tags: javascript, php, google-visualization

I'm using PHP to retrieve data from my MySQL-database and I want to insert it into a Google Chart (pie).

```
<?php
$result = mysqli_fetch_assoc(db_query("SELECT * FROM investments ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1;"));

echo '<div style="display: none;">';
foreach($result as $key => $value) {
    echo '<p class="investment_type">'. $key .'</p>';
    echo '<p class="investment_amount">'. $value .'</p>';
}
echo '</div>'

?>
<script>
var type = document.getElementsByClassName("investment_type");
var amount = document.getElementsByClassName("investment_amount");
var investment_type = [];
var investment_amount = [];
for(var i = 0; i < type.length; i++) {
    investment_type[i] = '"' + type[i].innerText + '"' || '"' + type[i].textContent + '"';
    investment_amount[i] = amount[i].innerText || amount[i].textContent;
}

google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
function drawChart() {
    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    data.addColumn('string', 'Investeringsområde');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Procent');

    var rows = [];
    for (var i = 2; i < investment_type.length; ++i) {
        rows[i] = [investment_type[i], investment_amount[i]];
    }

    alert(rows[3]);
    data.addRows(rows);

    var piechart_options = {title:'Portföljfördelning',
                            width:600,
                            height:400};

    var piechart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('piechart_div'));
    piechart.draw(data, piechart_options);
}
</script>

<div id="piechart_div" style="border: 1px solid #ccc" class="col-md-4"></div>
```

For some reason this part doesn't work:

```
data.addRows(rows);
```

Although if I try to alert for example rows[3] (as in the example) it gives the expected result so I know that the variables are correctly stored.

When I replace the above line with:

```
var rows = '[["2004", 400],["2005", 460],["2006", 1120],["2007", 540], ["2017", 540], ["2097", 540]]';
    data.addRows(JSON.parse(rows));
```

Then it works. I really have no idea what I'm doing wrong and I searched and searched. Could someone please help me out here?

Thanks in advance!

PS: I tried removing the quotations from the line:

```
investment_type[i] = '"' + type[i].innerText + '"' || '"' + type[i].textContent + '"';
```

Without successful result. I think there should be double quotations around strings in G. Charts, right?

Comment: you are selecting only one row here. why you're expecting multiple results?

Comment: Do you mean that

data.addRows(rows);

Only adds one row? I thought it added an array of an array?

Comment: I mean **mysqli_fetch_assoc**

Comment: I see. Yes I only want a pie chart with the columns of that one latest particular sql-result.

Comment: open your page source and see what you get from $result. it is nowhere near to something like ["2005", 460] pairs. Neither do I understand how do you expect multiple values from a single row

Comment: you have to add `parseInt(investment_amount[i])` in your for loop while creating the `rows` array without it you will have this error `Error: Type mismatch. Value ? does not match type number ...`

Comment: I got one row with multiple columns, hence multiple results? Or what do you mean by "multiple results"? I just want a pie chart showing one row (which has multiple columns, which are supposed to each (except for column 1 & 2 which are ID and date) be an area in the pie chart.

Comment: Thanks Amani. Now it's like this:

`for(var i = 0; i < type.length; i++) {
   investment_type[i] = '"' + type[i].innerText + '"' || '"' + type[i].textContent + '"';
  investment_amount[i] = amount[i].innerText || amount[i].textContent;
  parseInt(investment_amount[i]);
}

Still doesn't work though :/

Comment: try this `for (var i = 0; i < investment_type.length; ++i) {
             rows[i] =[investment_type[i], parseInt(investment_amount[i])];

         }`

Comment: Now it works!!! Thanks you so much :-)

Comment: I created a fiddle for you without the php part, and using `parseInt()` it works https://jsfiddle.net/amani1988/459hwkyd/1/ take a look that may help you

Comment: oh didn't saw your comment, glad to help :)